# User query operator in solr

Tags: solr, solr-query-syntax

I use solr 4.5.1

My data structure contains records and subrecords. Every record  is constructed from subrecords. Exist a lot of kind of subrecords. 
Exemple in XML :

```
 <doc>
  <recordId>10</recordId>
  <subRecordId>11</subRecordId>
  <SR1.FirstName>Kris</SR1.FirstName>//SR1 is name
  <SR1.LastName>Jenner</SR1.LastName>
  <SR1.MaidenName>Kardashian</SR1.MaidenName>
 <doc>

 <doc>
  <recordId>10</recordId>
  <subRecordId>12</subRecordId>
  <SR5.Country>USA</SR1.Country>
  <SR5.City>Los-Angeles</SR1.City>//SR5 is address
  <SR5.Street>125 street</SR1.Street>
  <SR5.Zip>98532</SR1.Zip>
 <doc>

 <doc>
  <recordId>10</recordId>
  <subRecordId>13</subRecordId>
  <SR5.Country>Australia</SR1.Country>//SR5 is address
  <SR5.City>Canberra</SR1.City>
  <SR5.Street>278 avenue</SR1.Street>
  <SR5.Zip>7511/SR1.Zip>
 <doc>
```

In the example: I have two kinds of subrecords: Name and Address. They belong to record 10.

I need to built query about name **and** address ,when name and address belong to same record .
q=SR5.Zip:7511 MyAnd SR1.FirstName:Kris

When the operator "MyAnd" merge the results by Record Id.

May be , Have solr operator like this ?

Can I add my own operator?

TNX

Comment: Wouldn't a simple `AND` and select unique `RecordId` work for you? You'd get only those records that have hits on `SR5.Zip` **and** `SR1.FirstName`.

Comment: It doesn't work. Use operator "AND" instead operator "and"

Comment: Ah, sorry, case mistake. But does the `AND` operator work for you? Instead of having to create your own operator?

Comment: Because I have documents with different fields . Operator "AND" return empty result. I have use operator merge of dufferent query .